# Find All images file size and width in directory

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, imagemagick

I'm trying to find all .png .jpg and .gif files in my directory. I'm getting the file sizes properly but unable to get image width (I'm using `imagemagick`) in log file.

Script code

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in ./*; 
do 
    echo "listing contents of dir: $d";  
    find . -iname "*.jpg" -type f -exec identify -format '%w %h %i' '{}' \; | awk '$1<300 || $2<300'
    find . \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.png"  -or -name "*.gif" \) -size "+120k" -type f  -exec ls -lah {} \; > sandip-log.txt 
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `identify -format` you must explicitly add a newline if you want one. Without it, all your widths are on one line, and if the first one doesn't match your awk condition, you will see nothing.

```
...-exec identify -format '%w %h %i\n' '{}' \; ...
```